# Turn Assembler algorithm to a Java Sequence calculator

Tags: java, sequence, calculator

When I enter "3" in my java code, it prints

3 will be multiplied by 3 and +1 
Value is 10

Any advice as to how I should modify it, so that it calculates the sequences correctly

```
    import javax.swing.*;
public class sequences {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            calculateSequences();
    }//ends main

    public static void calculateSequences()
        {
            int value;
            String valueInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Value");
            value = Integer.parseInt(valueInput);

            if(value == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Value is equal to 1, closing down");
                System.exit(0);

            }
            else if ((value%2)==0)
            {
            System.out.println(value + " will be divided by 2");
            value = value/2;
            System.out.println("Value is even " + value);

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(value + " will be multiplied by 3 and +1");
                value = 3*value+1;
                System.out.println("Value is " + value);

            }

        }//ends calculateSequences
}//ends class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the "go to start"

Here are the results from one test.

```
23 will be multiplied by 3 and + 1
Value is 70
70 will be divided by 2
Value is even 35
35 will be multiplied by 3 and + 1
Value is 106
106 will be divided by 2
Value is even 53
53 will be multiplied by 3 and + 1
Value is 160
160 will be divided by 2
Value is even 80
80 will be divided by 2
Value is even 40
40 will be divided by 2
Value is even 20
20 will be divided by 2
Value is even 10
10 will be divided by 2
Value is even 5
5 will be multiplied by 3 and + 1
Value is 16
16 will be divided by 2
Value is even 8
8 will be divided by 2
Value is even 4
4 will be divided by 2
Value is even 2
2 will be divided by 2
Value is even 1
Value is equal to 1, closing down
```

Here's your code with a while clause added.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Sequences {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculateSequences();
    }// ends main

    public static void calculateSequences() {
        int value;
        String valueInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Value");
        value = Integer.parseInt(valueInput);

        while (value > 0) {
            if (value == 1) {
                System.out.println("Value is equal to 1, closing down");
                System.exit(0);

            } else if ((value % 2) == 0) {
                System.out.println(value + " will be divided by 2");
                value = value / 2;
                System.out.println("Value is even " + value);

            } else {
                System.out.println(value + " will be multiplied by 3 and + 1");
                value = 3 * value + 1;
                System.out.println("Value is " + value);

            }
        }

    }// ends calculateSequences

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add iteration or recursion. Since this is Java, it would make most sense to use iteration.

This corresponds to the line "go to start ;" in the algorithm.

For this you can use a `while` loop, such as `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    process(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
}

private static void process(int n) {
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(n + " will be divided by 2");
            n = n/2;
            System.out.println("Value is even " + n);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(n + " will be multiplied by 3 and +1");
            n = 3*n+1;
            System.out.println("Value is " + n);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Value is equal to 1, closing down");
}
```

And the output:

```
3 will be multiplied by 3 and +1
Value is 10
10 will be divided by 2
Value is even 5
5 will be multiplied by 3 and +1
Value is 16
16 will be divided by 2
Value is even 8
8 will be divided by 2
Value is even 4
4 will be divided by 2
Value is even 2
2 will be divided by 2
Value is even 1
Value is equal to 1, closing down
```